# Checking all value from a json object to render the view

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty new to reactjs and I came to a situation where I cannot solved !

My app has a json array in this following format:

```
[
 {"email":"sample1@sample.com", "mobile":"000000", "iscompleted":"false"},
 {"email":"sample2@sample.com", "mobile":"000000", "iscompleted":"false"},
 {"email":"sample3@sample.com", "mobile":"000000", "iscompleted":"false"},
 {"email":"sample4@sample.com", "mobile":"000000", "iscompleted":"false"}
]
```

In my app logic, once I send a POST request and get its return response I update the `iscompleted` to `True`.

Then, I have a click button that refresh the application to its original state... however, I want to only display the button if all items in the json object is as  `"iscompleted":"true"`.

The question here, is how is the best approach to do that ?

I'm using react hooks for all my code, although, i dont know if its relevant.

I was thinking in a arrow function that returns true then i can use the following:

```
 {is_all_completed ? <StartAgainBtn /> : null}
```

Thank you

### Update

I'm using the following code logic at the end of the file. Also, I'm using const and arrow functions. As you can tell, I'm pretty new to react !

```
  return (
    <div>

      {props.recipients[0] && !props.report_sent ? <UserRecipientsTableView /> : null}

      {props.report_sent ? <ReportsSubmittedTable /> : null}

      {props.report_sent? <StartAgainBtn /> : null}

      {user_confirmed && !props.report_sent ? <SendReports /> : null}

    </div>
  );
};

export default Confirmation;
```

### Update2

Full code controller goes below:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import InputAdornment from "@material-ui/core/InputAdornment";


const Confirmation = props => {
  const [user_confirmed, setUserInputConfirmation] = useState('');
  const [recipients, updateRecipients] = useState(props.recipients);

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.setReportSent(true)
    props.recipients.forEach(function (element, index) {
      // Make it spin !
      updateRecipients([...recipients, element['iscomplete'] = false, element['errors'] = false])

      axios
        .post("/api/delivery/", element,
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${props.accessToken}`

          },
        })

        .then(function(response) {
          if (response.status === 202){
            updateRecipients([...recipients, element['iscomplete'] = true, element['errors'] = false])
            // for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(response.data)) {
            //   toast.success(`  ${key}: ${value}  `);
            // }

          }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          toast.error(`  Oh no! {${error.response.data}`);
          console.log(error.response.data);

            updateRecipients([...recipients, element['iscomplete'] = true, element['errors'] = true])

          // updateReportSentList([...report_sent_list, {element}])

          for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(error.response.data)) {
            toast.error(`  Oh no! ${key}: ${value}`);
          }

        });
    });
  };

  const UserConfirmationView = () => {
    if (user_confirmed)
    return (
      <div>
      <br/>
      <span>
        <h4>Please go ahead and click 'SEND IT'!</h4>
      </span>
      <br></br>
      </div>

    )
    else {
      return(
      <div className='user-consent-input'>
                <br></br>

      <TextField 
      id="input-with-icon-grid"
      label="" 
      placeholder='If you agree to the above, please type CONFIRMED in here ...'
      // variant="outlined"
      onChange={handleUserConfirmation}
      style = {{width: 500}}
      error={!user_confirmed ? true : false}
      // helperText={name.error ? name.helptext : ""}

      InputProps={{
        startAdornment: (
          <InputAdornment position="start">
            <i className="fas fa-check-double"></i>
          </InputAdornment>
        )
      }}

      />
      <br></br>
    </div>
      )

    }
  }

  const UserRecipientsTableView = () => {
    return (
<div className="card">
  <div className="card-body">
  <p className="you-are-about"> You are about to send <span className="userconfirm-view-filename-attr"> {props.filename}</span> to these contacts 
  below as <spam className="userconfirm-view-filename-attr"> {props.project_owner_name}</spam> being the project owner of the jobID: <spam className="userconfirm-view-filename-attr">{props.project_id}</spam>.</p>
    <br>
    </br>
    <p className="card-text">
    <div className="recipients-table">
        <table className="table table-hover table-sm">
          <thead className='thead-dark'>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Recipient's Name </th>
              <th scope="col">Recipient's Email</th>
              <th scope="col">Recipient's Mobile</th>
              <th scope="col">Project Desc</th>
              <th scope="col"></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          {/* Table body */}
          {props.allRecipients}
        </table>
        </div>

        <p>
        <div className="userconfirm-view">
        <br></br>
        <p className="you-are-about"> If you agree, please type <span className="userconfirm-view-filename-attr">CONFIRMED</span> into the box below.</p>

    <div className="col final-buttom" >
    <UserConfirmationView />    
    </div>
  </div>
        </p>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>


    );
  };


  const handleUserConfirmation = e => {
    if (e.target.value.trim().toUpperCase() === "CONFIRMED") {
      setUserInputConfirmation("Confirmed");
    } else 
    setUserInputConfirmation("");
    // setName({ error: true, helptext: "Wrong!" });

  };


  const SendReports = () => {
    if(user_confirmed){

          return (
           <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" 
           onClick={handleSubmit}
           fullWidth={true}
           size="medium" 
           style={{fontSize: "59px"}}
          // style={{minWidth: '300px', minHeight: '130px', marginTop: '40px', fontWeight: '700', lineHeight: '22px', marginBottom: '25px'}}
          // startIcon={<i className="fas fa-file-upload fa-6x"></i>}
           >
          <h4 className="send-it">Send it!</h4>

        </Button>

    );

    }else{
      return (
        alert("Can't submit it! Please start again.")
      )
    }

  };

  const statusStyle = (item) => {
    if (!item['iscomplete'] && (!item['errors'])) {
      //  spin loader ...
      return(<span><i className="fas fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x"></i> Loading ...</span>)

    } else if (item['iscomplete'] && (!item['errors'])) {
      //  if completed and no errros how Success
      return(<Button
        variant="contained"
        color="secondary"
        className='success-btn'
        startIcon={<i className="fas fa-check-circle fa-2x"></i>}
      >
        DELIVERED!
      </Button>)
      // return (<span><i className="fas fa-check-circle fa-2x"></i>Delivered!</span>);

    } else {
      //  Damn boy ! something went wrong!
        return(<Button 
          classes={{ label: 'failed-button' }}
          variant="contained"
          color="secondary"
          startIcon={<i className="fas fa-exclamation-triangle fa-2x"></i>}
        >
          Failed
        </Button>)
      // return (<span><i className="fas fa-exclamation-triangle fa-2x"></i>Please, try again ...</span>);
    }
}

  const ReportsSubmittedTable = () => {
    const tableAfterReportSent = props.recipients.map((item, index) =>
    <tbody key={index}>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">{item.client_name}</th>
        <td>{item.client_email}</td>
        <td>{item.client_mobile}</td>
        <td>{statusStyle(item)}</td>
        {/* <td>{statusStyle(item.iscomplete)}</td> */}

        {/* <td><i className="recipients-x-remove" onClick={() => removeTodo(index)}><span role='img'> ❌ </span></i></td> */}
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  ); 

    return (
<div className="card" onChange={ReportsSubmittedTable}>
  <div className="card-body">
    {/* <h5 className="card-title">I'm doing what you told me to ... Please, hold on!</h5> */}
    <br></br>
    {/* <h6 className="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">You are about to send <span>{props.filename}</span> to the following people: </h6> */}
    <p className="card-text">
    <div className="recipients-table">
        <table className="table table-hover table-sm">
          <thead className='thead-dark'>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Recipient's Name </th>
              <th scope="col">Recipient's Email</th>
              <th scope="col">Recipient's Mobile</th>
              <th scope="col">Status</th>
              {/* <th scope="col">Errors</th> */}
            </tr>
          </thead>
          {/* Table body */}
          {tableAfterReportSent}
        </table>
        </div>
        <p>
        <hr></hr>
        </p>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

    );
  };


  const StartAgainBtn = () => {
    if (props.report_sent){
      return (
        <div className="card completed">
          <div className="card-body">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col">
              <h4>Completed!</h4>
              <br></br>
              <h4>Want to send a new file ?</h4>
            </div>
            <div className="col">
              <Button
                variant="outlined"
                color="primary"
                size="large"
                onClick={e => props.resetfile()}
                style={{
                  minWidth: "100%",
                  minHeight: "100%",
                  // marginTop: "20px",
                  fontWeight: "600",
                  // lineHeight: "22px"
                }}
              >
          <i className="fas fa-redo fa-4x"></i>
              <h4 className="start-again">{     }Start Again!</h4>
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>

      );
    }
  }


  return (
    <div>

      {props.recipients[0] && !props.report_sent ? <UserRecipientsTableView /> : null}

      {props.report_sent ? <ReportsSubmittedTable /> : null}

      {props.report_sent? <StartAgainBtn /> : null}

      {user_confirmed && !props.report_sent ? <SendReports /> : null}

    </div>
  );
};

export default Confirmation;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

Create a function that takes the list and checks for `isComplete` property of each item on the array.

Then you can just call that function on your **ternary operator** `{isAllCompleted(JSON.parse(responseDataASJSON))? <StartAgainBtn /> : null}`

```
// param ="resultData" is the data received from Ajax Response. data must be a javascript object.
function isAllCompleted(data){

  for(let i =0; i < data.length; i++){
    if(data[i].isCompleted === "false"){
    // If any false value was found, return false
      // 
      return false;
    }
  }
  // At this point, no value was found to be false, 
  // because it wouldn't returned false based on the loop block
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, but, it did not work for me... I tried to implement this function in my code but it was giving me errors :(  I'm assuming because the return True will not continue to the rest of the code. So, is there a way to do the same using arrow functions like i have in the code? Sorry if I've being stupid... cherrs

Comment: Don't forget to pass `JSON.parse(yourResponse) ` before passing your data to the function because your data is a JSON format

Comment: I'm getting this error tho: ``` Line 322:1:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

  320 |     </div>
  321 |   );
> 322 | };
      | ^
  323 | 
  324 | export default Confirmation``` when i copy and paste your function into my code :/

Comment: The error is clear, so did you check Line 322 on your code?

Comment: Can you please include your Controller code on your question?

Comment: Cool I saw the problem on my function. I had forgotten the opening `"{"` for my `if()` statement, so I have updated it. Could you run your code again with my function after fixing that opening `{`

Comment: Cool I saw the problem on my function. I had forgotten the opening `"{"` for my `if()` statement

Comment: It did not work :/ App loads, but crashes (blank page) when I get to the confirmation controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JS function `.every()` for easy iteration through the JSON object.

```
is_all_completed = YourJSONObj.every(function (n) { return n.iscompleted === "true";})
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

That ternary will work fine.  I typically like to simplify it even more with the following:

```
{ is_all_completed && <StartAgainBtn /> }
```

Just makes things a little more concise but either way works.